# Can htaccess redirects outiside public_html

Tags: .htaccess

I want to access www.something.com/abc.php but abc.php resides at /home/myfolder/abc.php, outside public_html. Folder structure like below:

```
/home
    /myfolder
        abc.php
    /public_html
```

Answer (score 1):

If the root of your web directory is `/public_html/`, then no, you cannot redirect or even navigate to a lower directory. You can *include* `abc.php` in some PHP page that resides in `/public_html/`, however.

**Example:**

/public_html/index.php

```
<?php
include "../myfolder/abc.php"
```

---

Strictly academically speaking, you could set up a [symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory) from a folder in `/public_html/` to your lower directory, but it may have *massive* security implications.

**Example:**

```
/public_html/myfolder --> /myfolder
```

Comment: That I cant do. I need to access this beyond public_html

Comment: If you set up a symlink from a folder in /public_html/ to your lower directory, then that will work, but it has massive security implications